# Undefined local variable or method "last_email"

Tags: rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara

I'm running into issues on how to get my Devise Password Reset Test working correctly as I run into an error in my code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Passwords" do
    describe "Forgot Password" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        it 'should reset a users password' do
            reset_mailer
            visit '/'
            click_link 'Sign In'
            fill_in 'Password', :with => 'fakepass'
            fill_in 'Email', :with => user.email
            click_button "Sign in"
            current_path.should == user_session_path
            page.should have_content 'Invalid email or password.'
            click_link 'Forgot your password?'
            current_path.should == new_user_password_path
            page.should have_content 'Forgot Password'
            fill_in 'Email', :with => user.email
            click_button 'Send me password reset instructions'
            current_path.should == user_session_path
            page.should have_content 'You will receive an email'

            last_email.to.should include(user.email)
            open_email(user.email)
            current_email.first(:link, 'Change My password').click

            within('body') do
                page.should have_content 'Change Your Password'
            end

            fill_in "user[password]", :with => "password"
            fill_in "user[password_confirmation]", :with => "password"
            click_button "Change My Password"

            within('body') do
                page.should have_content 'password changed.'
            end

        end
    end
end
```

Than my error:

```
Passwords Forgot Password should reset a users password
     Failure/Error: last_email.to.should include(user.email)
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `last_email' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0xb788c18>
```

Why do I get this error? How do I correct it?

**UPDATE**

```
features/email_steps.rb

# Commonly used email steps
#
# To add your own steps make a custom_email_steps.rb
# The provided methods are:
#
# last_email_address
# reset_mailer
# open_last_email
# visit_in_email
# unread_emails_for
# mailbox_for
# current_email
# open_email
# read_emails_for
# find_email
#
# General form for email scenarios are:
#   - clear the email queue (done automatically by email_spec)
#   - execute steps that sends an email
#   - check the user received an/no/[0-9] emails
#   - open the email
#   - inspect the email contents
#   - interact with the email (e.g. click links)
#
```

Updated Code:

```
open_last_email.to.should include(user.email)
open_email(user.email)
current_email.first(:link, 'Change My Password').click

Failure/Error: current_email.first(:link, 'Change My Password').click
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `first' for #<Mail::Message:0xb560dc8>
```

Comment: last_email is not defined anywhere, yet you use it here: `last_email.to.should include(user.email)`

Comment: @Arjan Where do or should I define it at?

Comment: I don't know. Did you write this spec yourself, or did you get it somewhere? If the latter is the case, could you point me to where you got it from. That might help.

Comment: @Arjan I wrote most of it and I got the "email block" from here :https://github.com/dockyard/capybara-email/wiki/sample-devise-spec-with-rspec,-factory-girl,-launchy-and-capybara-email

Comment: I see, did you add the devise test_helpers? That might solve the issue. Check https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers

Comment: I found the issue. It's for my folder at `/home/user/prapp/features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb`. It has certain methods in their. I was able to get past the the `last_email` correct issue and now I'm looking at how to solve the `current_email.first(:link, 'Change My password').click` since it gives me the error `undefined method "first"`. I'll post the email steps and my updated area of code so you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working. The problem lies in the `email_steps.rb`. I had no idea about it as I'm running a premade application for practice.

In regards the code area I was having trouble with:

My code with errors was this:

```
last_email.to.should include(user.email)
open_email(user.email)
current_email.first(:link, 'Change My password').click
```

My new code that now past the test:

```
open_last_email.to.should include(user.email)
open_email(user.email)
click_first_link_in_email
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me, btw I'm using gem 'capybara-email' with rspec

```
open_email(user.email)
current_email.click_link 'Change my password'
```